# Fixing a letter frequency analyser in C

Tags: c

I'm new to programming and I need some help in getting my program to work because I am kind of stuck at the moment. It's suppose to count the frequency of a letter and other characters for an input text file then print out the results but nothing happens when I do insert a file (but it does compile). This is what I have so far. I think its because I don't return the results of the array back into the main function so it can print out, but I am not sure how to do this. Would you need to use malloc (e.g. `int *alphabetCount = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*ALPHABET_SIZE);`) for the array then free it later?

Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ALPHABET_SIZE 26
#define FIRST_LC_LETTER 'a'
#define LAST_LC_LETTER 'z'
#define FIRST_UC_LETTER 'A'
#define LAST_UC_LETTER 'Z'

int freqAnalysis (int inputChar);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

   int inputChar = getchar();
   int position = 0;

   char alphabet [ALPHABET_SIZE] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j',
      'k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
   int alphabetCount [ALPHABET_SIZE];

   freqAnalysis (inputChar);

   while (position < ALPHABET_SIZE) {
      printf ("Letter %c: %d\n",alphabet[position],alphabetCount[position]);
      position++;
   }
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int freqAnalysis (int inputChar) {      
   int counter;
   int numbers;
   int spaces;
   int specialChar;

   int alphabetCount [ALPHABET_SIZE];
   while (counter < ALPHABET_SIZE) {
      counter = 0;
      alphabetCount [counter] = 0;
      counter ++;
   }

   while (inputChar != EOF) {
      if (inputChar >= FIRST_LC_LETTER && inputChar <= LAST_LC_LETTER) {
         alphabetCount [inputChar - FIRST_LC_LETTER] ++;
      } else if (inputChar>=FIRST_UC_LETTER && inputChar<=LAST_UC_LETTER) {
         alphabetCount [inputChar - FIRST_UC_LETTER] ++;
      } else if (inputChar >= 0 && inputChar <= 9) {
         numbers = 0;
         numbers ++;
      } else if (inputChar == ' ') {
         spaces = 0;
         spaces ++;
      } else {
         specialChar = 0;
         specialChar ++;
      }
   }
   printf ("Numbers: %d\nSpaces: %d\n Special characters: %d\n", numbers, 
           spaces, specialChar);
}
```

Comment: 0) `freqAnalysis (inputChar);` : only one character pass to function.

Comment: 1) `while (counter < ALPHABET_SIZE) { counter = 0;` : `counter = 0` move to before this loop.

Comment: 2) `while (inputChar != EOF) {` : `inputChar` does not change in this loop.

Comment: `Would you need to use malloc (e.g. int *alphabetCount = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*ALPHABET_SIZE);) for the array then free it later?` yes. or use `static int alphabetCount [ALPHABET_SIZE];`

Comment: 3) `numbers = 0;` etc.. move to before loop.

Comment: thank you. Sorry but I'm not sure how to get all the characters to pass through to the function then return all the values back to main.

Comment: Digits are `'0'` through `'9'`, not `0` through `9`. Apostrophes make digit characters, without them you are using decimal numbers, that is ASCII codes of characters.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a similar approach to consider. It has been written to remove dependencies from all libc header files except `stdio.h`. Rather than calling the character classification functions in `ctype.h` it relies on the ASCII values for each of the characters to set the `alphabetCount` indexes. Neither approach is better/worse than the other, they just illustrate different ways of approaching the same problem with the various tools available.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ALPHABET_SIZE 26

void freqAnalysis (FILE *fp, int *cnt);

int main (void)
{
    int position = 0;
    char *alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int alphabetCount[ALPHABET_SIZE] = {0};

    printf ("\nThe frequency analysis of the input characters:\n\n");

    freqAnalysis (stdin, alphabetCount);

    for (position = 0; position < ALPHABET_SIZE; position++)
        printf ("    %c/%c  : %d\n", alphabet[position] - 32,
                alphabet[position], alphabetCount[position]);

    return 0;
}

void freqAnalysis (FILE *fp, int *cnt)
{
    int c, numbers, spaces, specialChar;
    c = numbers = spaces = specialChar = 0;

    while ((c = fgetc (fp)) != '\n' && c != EOF) 
    {
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            cnt[c - 'A']++;
        else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            cnt[c - 'a']++;
        else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            numbers++;
        else if ( c == ' ' )
            spaces++;
        else
            specialChar++;

    }
    printf (" Numbers : %d\n Spaces  : %d\n Special : %d\n\n", numbers, spaces, specialChar);
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/charcount <<<"The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over 1001 Lazy Dogs."

The frequency analysis of the input characters:

 Numbers : 4
 Spaces  : 8
 Special : 1

    A/a  : 1
    B/b  : 1
    C/c  : 1
    D/d  : 1
    E/e  : 2
    F/f  : 1
    G/g  : 1
    H/h  : 1
    I/i  : 1
    J/j  : 1
    K/k  : 1
    L/l  : 1
    M/m  : 1
    N/n  : 1
    O/o  : 4
    P/p  : 1
    Q/q  : 1
    R/r  : 2
    S/s  : 2
    T/t  : 1
    U/u  : 2
    V/v  : 1
    W/w  : 1
    X/x  : 1
    Y/y  : 1
    Z/z  : 1
```

Comment: What are the results of your program for input "The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over 1001 Lazy Dogs" ?

Comment: Wrong.... fixing `:p` I originally had a `char *numbers = "0123456789";` and `int *numbersCount[10] = {0};`

Answer (score 0):

policy of modified to be processed by passing a file handle and an secured array in main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define ALPHABET_SIZE 26
#define FIRST_LC_LETTER 'a'
#define FIRST_UC_LETTER 'A'

void freqAnalysis(FILE *fin, int counter[]);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int position;
    char alphabet[ALPHABET_SIZE] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j',
    'k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};//unused
    int alphabetCount[ALPHABET_SIZE] = {0};

    freqAnalysis(stdin, alphabetCount);

    for (position = 0; position < ALPHABET_SIZE; position++){
        printf ("Letter %c: %d\n", alphabet[position], alphabetCount[position]);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void freqAnalysis(FILE *fp, int alphabetCount[]) {
    int inputChar;
    int numbers , spaces, specialChar;

    numbers = spaces = specialChar = 0;

   while((inputChar=fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
      if(islower(inputChar)){
         alphabetCount[inputChar - FIRST_LC_LETTER]++;
      } else if(isupper(inputChar)) {
         alphabetCount[inputChar - FIRST_UC_LETTER]++;//this relies on order of character codes.
      } else if(isdigit(inputChar)) {
         numbers++;
      } else if(inputChar == ' ') {//isspace(inputChar)
         spaces++;
      } else {
         specialChar ++;
      }
   }
   printf("Numbers: %d\nSpaces: %d\nSpecial characters: %d\n", numbers, 
          spaces, specialChar);
}
```